# Disable Alt+` keyboard Shortcut in Linux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, cinnamon

I want to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> key for my editor

Now when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> it will show the current tab of the active window.

Comment: Did you try unbinding it in the keyboard shortcuts tool?

Comment: keyboard shortcut tool? do u mean System Setting > Keyboard > Shortcut? I can't found that ALT+` there

Comment: "gsettings list-recursively | grep Alt" also can't found ALT+`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the key <kbd>`</kbd> is called **Above_Tab**, I'm didn't notice this before, I don't know what the name is :lol:

show relevance ALT shortcuts

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep Alt
```

output

```
org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm switch-group ['<Alt>Above_Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group ['<Super>Above_Tab', '<Alt>Above_Tab']
```

remove the shortcut

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm switch-group []
```

now I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> for my editor